# Why is this curve not closed?

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

Consider the curve $$\gamma (t) =\left( \cos(t^3+t), \sin(t^3+t) \right) $$

I am asked to show that a reparamaterization of a closed curve is not necessarily  closed. The book provides this as a counter example. Why is this curve not closed?

I think I am having some trouble showing curves are open/closed.

Comment: you should be far more precise about what the book says. For example, the typical circle is given with some qualification such as $0 \leq t \leq 2 \pi$ when your $t^3 + t$ is returned to just $t.$ Maybe they want some endpoints, or maybe they want something completely different; context needed.

Comment: Doesn't that depend on the range of $t$? If the range is $0 \le t \le T$ where $T^3+T = 2\pi$ it appears as it would be closed. Or the book must have another definition than $\gamma(a) = \gamma(b)$ where $a$ and $b$ are endpoints.

Comment: The book actually doesn't provide info on a range of t. If t falls on some interval, the result is obvious, but the book does not provide a range for t, which leads me to believe that this is an open curve.

Comment: As far as I know, there's no such thing as an open curve (at least it has no standard meaning). The opposite of a closed curve is a curve that is not closed.

Comment: I thought so. Feel free to edit the post.

Comment: @skyking the book calls closed curves those curves that satisfy $\gamma (t) = \gamma (t+T) \forall t$ for some non zero T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\gamma(t) = (cos (t^3+t), sin (t^3+t))$ and assume that there were such a $T \ne 0$ that made $\gamma(t+T) = \gamma(t)$. Then it would be true for its derivative too (ie $\gamma'(t+T) = \gamma'(t)$).

This would especially mean that $\gamma'(T) = \gamma'(0)$, but $\gamma'(t) = (3t^2+1)(-sin(t^3+t), cos(t^3+t))$. But $|\gamma'(0)| = 1$, but $|\gamma'(T)| = 3T^2+1$, and since $T \ne 0$ then $\gamma'(0) \ne \gamma'(T)$.

Comment: Concise and simple proof, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here are two attempts to guess what your book is after.
If the book really gives no more context and no interval of definition, I find this example confusing.
A formula alone is not a curve; a curve is a function that can be defined using a formula, but also a domain is needed (and it is not implicitly understood clearly enough in this case).

**Attempt 1.**
The curve $\sigma:[0,2\pi]\to\mathbb R^2$ given by $\sigma(t)=(\cos(t),\sin(t))$ is closed.
The mapping $\phi:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, $\phi(t)=t+t^3$ is a valid change of parametrization, so $\sigma\circ\phi$ is a reparametrization of $\sigma$.
In fact, $\sigma\circ\phi=\gamma$ (the formula you gave), but $\gamma:[0,2\pi]\to\mathbb R^2$ is not a closed curve.

This is a bit silly, though, since the domain of $\gamma$ should be $\phi^{-1}([0,2\pi])$, not $[0,2\pi]$.
A reparametrization should also change the interval of definition.

**Attempt 2.**
It might be that your book requires that a closed curve $\gamma:[a,b]\to\mathbb R^n$ satisfies not only $\gamma(a)=\gamma(b)$ but also $\gamma'(a)=\gamma'(b)$.
This only makes sense if you require $\gamma$ to be differentiable in the first place; you did not mention about differentiability assumptions.
If $T$ is the number satisfying $T+T^3=2\pi$, then your $\gamma$ defined on $[0,T]$ does not satisfy the second condition.

I find this silly, too, since if matching derivatives are required at endpoints, then the definition of reparametrization should include conditions on the derivatives at the endpoints to remove this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt. I'm using Andrew Pressely's introduction to differential geometry, for what it is worth.

Comment: @user3600497, you are welcome. It seems that the problem was in the definition. (This just appeared in the comments above.) The book's definition of a closed curve is not the standard one. Most would make a distinction between a closed curve and a periodic curve.